# How to convert a ZPL code into a image using c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, converters, zpl-ii

I'm getting a response back in Zpl code from a service integrated in my system all I want is to convert the Zpl code into image

I have tried http://labelary.com/ but it has limitation on free public services where its limitless service is too expensive.

I have also tried reading zpl code manual to create a parser but failed
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: You need to parse about 1500 pages of specifications. or get someones library.. and before you ask, we dont ask for libraries here

Comment: @TheGeneral There is only one library that I found is free and can convert zpl to image but as I mentioned above it has limitation. I was hoping if someone already created a parser or can guide me a little on parsing

Comment: Can you show us where or why you failed to write your own parser?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code at https://github.com/BinaryKits/BinaryKits.Zpl/tree/master/src/BinaryKits.Zpl.Viewer

It will give you an image

[image: zpl preview]

Answer (score 0):

The only way to convert a ZPL code into a PNG that look exactly the label is to use a Zebra printer for rendering it ;o).

Industrial Zebra have an embedded web site that allow you to post ZPL code and get a PNG in return. This is what [zpldesigner](https://www.zpldesigner.com) use.

Labelary and other software can only "simulate" ZPL code.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Using Api request i.e

```
byte[] zpl = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("^xa^cfa,50^fo100,100^fdHello World^fs^xz");

// adjust print density (8dpmm), label width (4 inches), label height (6 inches), and label index (0) as necessary
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/png"; // omit this line to get PNG images back
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = zpl.Length;

var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(zpl, 0, zpl.Length);
requestStream.Close();

try {
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var fileStream = File.Create("label.pdf"); // change file name for PNG images
    responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    responseStream.Close();
    fileStream.Close();
} catch (WebException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Status);
}
```

reference [Link](http://labelary.com/service.html)